# Migrating a Data Directory from 2.1.4 to 2.4.3

Tags: geoserver, migration

Recently, I got a new server and I installed the latest Geoserver version (2.4.3.).
Now I need to migrate all data (layers, stores, styles, users, workspaces, postgis stores...) from older geoserver 2.1.4 to the new one.
Anyone know how can I do it?
Just move the data directory ?

Best regards

Comment: Based on http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/migrating.html#migrating-data-directory I don't think it is going to work "by magic". You're going to (somehow) create the security files that are needed. If I knew the "(somehow)" I would have put an answer instead of this comment :-( Safest way would be to set up new server, script REST queries to the old server, script matching REST uploads to the new server, and check everything at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually first try to just move the data directory. Back it up, of course, or run on a test machine first. But if you're migrating forward then GeoServer is designed to just automatically add the new files you need. Going *backwards* in versions with a newer data directory is much less supported, and that's why the data directory documentation page includes information on all the files that get modified, afaik.

2.1.4 to 2.4.3 is a larger jump than most people do, but it's worth trying. I believe it *should* work. Just back up everything and check the results. All the new security files should be there automatically.

Comment: As I don't have custom groups, rules, etc... The migration was very easy, I just needed to re-create the users on new geoserver and move the workspaces and styles from older geoserver into the data directory on new geoserver and restart the tomcat. After this, voilà, all layes are working very well.
Thank you all.